# How to show $U$ and $V$ are not independent random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, negative-binomial

$U$ stands for the number of trials to get the first head,
$V$ stands for the number of trials to get two heads.

I used hand-waving proof, saying that you could not have the two heads trials without having the first head occur, but I don't know how to mathematically prove that the two random variables must be dependent.

Comment: Find functions $f$ and $g$ so that $Ef(U)G(V)\ne Ef(U) Eg(V)$.

Comment: What's the probability that $U=3$ and $V=2$? What's the probability of those events separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables are independent if $P(U=u, V=v)=P(U=u)\cdot P(V=v)$ for all values $u,v$.

Therefore, to prove that the variables are **not** independent, all you need to do is find one pair $u,v$ such that

$P(U=u, V=v)\neq P(U=u)\cdot P(V=v)$

To do that, you can go one of two ways:

**Option $1$**: Try a little brute force search. Plug in a couple values $u,v$ and see if the equation holds.

**Option $2$**: Since the right side of the equation will always be nonzero, think about how you could make the left side zero. Can you think of some pair of numbers $u,v$ such that it's impossible to get two heads in $v$ trials, but only one head in $u$ trials?

Comment: I attempted to do option 1 but don't know how to derive the joint distribution of u,v...which is why I posted this question to see if someone could give me some suggestion on the most generic way of solving this question...

Comment: @ChloeZhou Maybe try option 2?